# Scaling the sigmoid output

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, classification, sigmoid

I am training a Network on images for binary classification. The input images are normalized to have pixel values in the range[0,1]. Also, the weight matrices are initialized from a normal distribution. However, the output from my last Dense layer with sigmoid activation yields values with a very minute difference for the two classes. For example -

> `output for class1- 0.377525 output for class2- 0.377539`

The difference for the classes comes after 4 decimal places. Is there any workaround to make sure that the output for class 1 falls around 0 to 0.5 and for class 2 , it falls between 0.5 to 1.

**Edit:**

I have tried both the cases.

Case 1 -  Dense(1, 'sigmoid') with binary crossentropy
Case 2-   Dense(2, 'softmax') with binary crossentropy

For case1, the output values differ by  a very small amount as mentioned in the problem above. As such , i am taking mean of the predicted values to act as threshold for classification. This works upto some extent, but not a permanent solution.

For case 2 - the prediction overfits to one class only.

A sample code : -

```
inputs = Input(shape = (128,156,1))
x = Conv2D(.....)(inputs)
x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = Maxpooling2D()(x)
...
.
.
flat=Flatten()(x)

out = Dense(1,'sigmoid')(x)
model = Model(inputs,out)
model.compile(optimizer='adamax',loss='binary_crossentropy',metrics=['binary_accuracy'])
```

Comment: Is your output `Dense(2, activation='sigmoid')` or `Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')`?

Comment: I have edited the question. I have tried both the things as you mentioned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are confusing a binary classification architecture with a 2 label multi-class classification architecture setup.

Since you mention the probabilities for the 2 classes, `class1` and `class2`, you have, set up a single label multi-class setup. That means, you are trying to predict the probabilities of 2 classes, where a sample can have only one of the labels at a time.

In this setup, it's proper to use `softmax` instead of `sigmoid`. Your loss function would be `binary_crossentropy` as well.

[image]

Right now, with the multi-label setup and `sigmoid` activation, you are independently predicting the probability of a sample being `class1` and `class2` simultaneously (aka, multi-label multi-class classification).

Once you change to `softmax` you should see more significant differences between the probabilities IF the sample actually definitively belongs to one of the 2 classes and if your model is well trained & confident about its predictions (validation vs training results)

Answer (score 0):

First, I would like to say the information you provided is insufficient to exactly debug your problem, because you didn't provide any code of your model and optimizer. I suspect there might be an error in the labels, and I also suggest you use a `softmax` activation fuction instead of the `sigmoid` function in the final layer, although it will still work through your approach, binary classification problems must output one single node and loss must be binary cross entropy.

If you want to receive an accurate solution, please provide more information.